# Low accuracy when fine-tuning BERT for question answering

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

I'm trying to fine-tune CamemBERT (french version of Roberta) for question answering.

At the first I'm using **CamemBERT** model to generate the input embedding of question and text and a output **linear layer** to output the start and end logits that corresponds to the start and the end of the answer.

In the official results in the paper the performance for question answering is **(88 %, 77%)** of **(F1 score, EM)** but the results I get are **(71%, 46%)**.

My question is why the results are not close enough ?

This is a part of the script that I'm using to train and evaluate the model on FQuAD dataset with the same hyper-parameters as the official model:

```
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 384
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 12
n_epochs = 3
learning_rate = 3e-5
EVAL_BATCH_SIZE = 12
dropout = 0
BERT_TYPE =  "fmikaelian/camembert-base-fquad"

class CamemBERTQA(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,bert_type, hidden_size, num_labels):
       super(CamemBERTQA, self).__init__()
       self.bert_type = bert_type
       self.hidden_size = hidden_size
       self.num_labels = num_labels
       self.camembert = AutoModel.from_pretrained(self.bert_type)
       self.qa_outputs = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.num_labels)

   def forward(self, input_ids):
       output = self.camembert(input_ids = input_ids)[0]
       logits = self.qa_outputs(output)
       start_logits, end_logits = logits.split(1, dim=-1)
       start_logits = start_logits.squeeze(-1)
       end_logits = end_logits.squeeze(-1)
       outputs = (start_logits, end_logits,)
       return outputs

def train_eval_model(model, n_epochs, scheduler=None):
   train_lossess = []
   valid_lossess = []
   avg_train_losses = []
   avg_valid_losses = [] 
   res = []
   for epoch in trange(n_epochs):
       #######################################################################################
       ################################### train the model ###################################
       #######################################################################################
       model.train()
       for batch, d in enumerate(tqdm_notebook(train_dataloader, desc="Iteration")):
           ids = d['ids']
           start_pos = d['start_pos']
           end_pos = d['end_pos']
           ids = ids.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
           start_pos = start_pos.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
           end_pos = end_pos.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
           optimizer.zero_grad()
           start_and_end_scores = model(ids) # Forward pass return start and end positions
           loss = loss_func(start_and_end_scores, start_pos, end_pos)
           loss.backward()
           optimizer.step()
           if scheduler is not None:
               scheduler.step()
           train_lossess.append(loss.item())
       ##########################################################################################    
       ################################### validate the model ###################################
       ##########################################################################################
       model.eval() 
       pred_s = None
       pred_e = None
       # eval_loss = 0.0
       # eval_steps = 0

       for batch, d in enumerate(eval_dataloader):
           ids = d['ids']
           start_pos = d['start_pos']
           end_pos = d['end_pos']

           ids = ids.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
           start_pos = start_pos.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
           end_pos = end_pos.to(device, dtype = torch.long)

           with torch.no_grad():
               start_and_end_scores = model(ids)
               loss = loss_func(start_and_end_scores, start_pos, end_pos)
               valid_lossess.append(loss.item())
           # eval_steps += 1
           if pred_s is None:
               pred_s = start_and_end_scores[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
               pred_e = start_and_end_scores[1].detach().cpu().numpy()
           else:
               pred_s = np.append(pred_s, start_and_end_scores[0].detach().cpu().numpy(), axis=0)
               pred_e = np.append(pred_e, start_and_end_scores[1].detach().cpu().numpy(), axis=0)
       pred_start = np.argmax(pred_s, axis=1)
       pred_end = np.argmax(pred_e, axis=1)
       res.append([pred_start,pred_end])
       train_loss = np.average(train_lossess)
       valid_loss = np.average(valid_lossess)
       avg_train_losses.append(train_loss)
       avg_valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
       epoch_len = len(str(n_epochs))
       print_msg = (f'[{epoch:>{epoch_len}}/{n_epochs:>{epoch_len}}] ' +
                    f'train_loss: {train_loss:.5f} ' +
                    f'valid_loss: {valid_loss:.5f}')
       print(print_msg)
       train_lossess = []
       valid_lossess = []
   return  model, avg_train_losses, avg_valid_losses, res
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your question will ever be answered.
Look here for examples to learn from:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/question-answering